# replace line feed

Tags: php

A php echo text with no HTML markup.

```
1. one
2. two
3. three
4. four
5. five
```

How do I make it remove the linefeed?

```
1. one<br>2. two<br>3. three<br>4. four<br>5. five
```

I tried nl2br, string replacement still doesn't replace properly.

Comment: Please supply: 1) What did you try (code), 2) what was the result and 3) How did it differ from the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace it:

```
$some_text = '
1. one
2. two
3. three
4. four
5. five
';

echo preg_replace('~\d+\.~', '', $some_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

nl2br is supposed to work for this.

Answer (score 0):

try to mix HTML and PHP

```
<?php $list=array('one','two','three','four','five'); ?>
<ul >
<?php foreach ($list as $k=>$v) { ?>
    <li style="display: inline;"><?php printf("%d.%s ",$k+1,$v);?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```